# Replace regex with multiple matches by corresponding capture groups

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to use JS to remove href tags from a string and leave only the link text. The desired behavior is as follows:

```
<a href='www.google.com'>google</a>, <a href='www.bing.com'>bing</a>, and so on..
```

should become:

```
google, bing, and so on..
```

The regex I came up with that (partly) works is as follows:

```
> const regex = /<a.+href=.*>([^<]*)< *\/a *>/
```

On strings with one match, this works fine:

```
> "<a href='www.google.com'>google</a> test".replace(regex, '$1')
'google test'
```

However, on strings with multiple matches this replacements leads to some (to me) unexpected behavior:

```
> const multString = "<a href='www.google.com'>google</a>, <a href='www.bing.com'>bing</a>, and so on.."
> multString.replace(regex, '$1');
'bing, and so on..'
```

How can the regex be constructed (or the execution be changed) so that the matches get replaced by their respective capture groups?

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the solution was simpler than expected. It is enough to just remove any html tags:

```
> const multString = "<a href='www.google.com'>google</a>, <a href='www.bing.com'>bing</a>, and so on.."
> multString.replace(/<[^>]+>/gm, '')
'google, bing, and so on..'
```